# absl:Found untraced functions such as _update_step_xla while saving (showing 1 of 1)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

WARNING:absl:Found untraced functions such as _update_step_xla while saving (showing 1 of 1). These functions will not be directly callable after loading.

what's the untraced functions in my model?
and my tensorflow and keras version:2.11.0

```
inputs = keras.Input(shape=(7, 3,))
x = keras.layers.Flatten()(inputs)
x = keras.layers.Dense(units=16)(x)
x = keras.layers.Dense(units=16)(x)
x = keras.layers.Dense(units=16)(x)
x = keras.layers.Dense(units=16)(x)
x = keras.layers.Dense(units=16)(x)
x = keras.layers.Dense(10, activation="softmax")(x)
model = keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=x)

model.summary()

model.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.RMSprop(learning_rate=1e-3),
              loss=keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy())
callbacks = [
    keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(filepath='save', monitor='val_accuracy'),
    keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir='logs/')
]
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
history = model.fit(tx, ty, batch_size=32, epochs=100, callbacks=callbacks)enter code here
```

Answer (score -1):

These are just warnings which will not impact running the above code and can be safely ignored. You can suppress this warning by adding the following code at the top of your code.

```
import absl.logging
absl.logging.set_verbosity(absl.logging.ERROR)
```